# OpenCL AMD S10000 dual GPU execution

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I have the S10000 AMD GPU, which has 2 GPUs inside. When I run clinfo the output looks like these are treated as separate GPUs. To run my kernel across both of these GPUs do I need to create 2 separate openCL queues and partition my work-groups? Do these two GPUs share memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create separate command queues for each GPU and manually partition the workload between them. The GPUs do not share memory, so you will also have to make sure data is transferred to both GPUs as necessary. If you create a single context containing both GPUs, the implementation will automatically deal with moving buffers between the GPUs as and when needed. However, in my experience it is often better to do this explicitly, as sometimes the implementation will generate false dependencies between kernels that both use the same buffer and will serialise kernel execution.